# Checkbox select all depending on form ID

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, toggle, fieldset

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("foo");
  for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="one">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" onClick="toggle(this)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="two">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" onClick="toggle(this)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="three">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" onClick="toggle(this)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to use the same javascript function to target the three different select all forms according to ID. With this function I now toggle all checkboxes, but I want to toggle all checkboxes in each form, so I don't toggle all checkboxes in all three forms at the same time.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(source);
  for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="one">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="button" name="foo1" onClick="toggle(this.name)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="two">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="button" name="foo2" onClick="toggle(this.name)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="three">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="button" name="foo3" onClick="toggle(this.name)" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've changed the radio toggle for "All" to button, hope this answers your question overall

Comment: Yes, but the above solution is to change the HTML checkbox names. Please check below answer with just update the javascript code to relevant to you question.

Answer (score 5):

Please update below function of javascript it will get specific form selected checkbox

```
function toggle(source) {
      var parent_form = source.parentElement.parentNode;      
      var checkboxes = parent_form.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
      }
}
```

It will be depending on the form of ID.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle(source) {
debugger;
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(source);
  for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = !checkboxes[i].checked;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="one">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle('foo1')" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo1" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="two">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle('foo2')" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo2" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>  

<form id="three">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Select Quarter / 2017</legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggle('foo3')" />All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q1 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q2 2017<br>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q3 2017<br> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo3" >Q4 2017<br>   
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: question is related to get form based on selected id, here you have changed the checkbox names